# Check a user input value against values in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filereader

I have text file. there around 1000 lines in it, each line contains a  8 letter alpha  numeric word for example my text file looks like this

```
TEST1234
T1E2A334
12RR8912
```

and so on. this file is located on the server in a folder called TestCodes

Now I have an html file called `test.html` where in this file I have input textbox where the user enters the testcode he/she has with them

I have button called Verify. when this input button is clicked I want to check the user inputed value against the contents in the text file.

If the testcode exists in the text file then display a button called Procced if not display an error message called invalid.

I know how to write the if condition but I have no idea how to check it against the text file

**HTML**

```
<div class="user-input">
    <input type="text" name="test-code" id="test-code" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Verify Code" name="verify-code" id="verify-code" />
</div>
<div id="TestRegister">
    <form id="club" action="/Proceed.html" method="post" autocomplete="off">
        <input type="submit" value="Proceed Registration" name="proceed-register" />
    </form>
</div>
<div id="TestError">
    <span>Please check the code again, its not valid</span>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TestRegister").hide();
    $("#TestError").hide();

    $.get("testcodes.txt", function (data) {
        var lines = data.split("\n");

        // this is where I am stuck. how to pass the above to ARRAY
        $("#verify-code").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ( /* here I need to check against the user input value, if they are equal */ ) {
                $("#TestRegister").show();
                $("TestError").hide();
            } else {
                $("#TestRegister").hide();
                $("TestError").show();
            }
        }
        });     


</script>
```

How can I pass text from testcodes to an Array and then check the user input value against this array? If the user input value is present in the array then I want to show `#TestRegister`, and if not, or if the input value is blank or null, show `#TestError`.

Thanks and appreciate any tips.

Comment: You haven't closed the brackets on `$(document).ready({ ..`. Also, you forgot the `#` in `1$('TestError')`.

Comment: I [beautified](http://jsbeautifier.com) your code and it makes the mistakes a bit more obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var lines;

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#TestRegister").hide();
    $("#TestError").hide();

    $.get("testcodes.txt", function (data) {
        lines = data.split("\n");
    });

    $("#verify-code").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (lines.indexOf($("#test-code").val()) !== -1 && $("#test-code").val().length == 8) {
            $("#TestRegister").show();
            $("TestError").hide();
        } else {
            $("#TestRegister").hide();
            $("TestError").show();
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but its not working no matter what i type is always show the error message

Comment: You also had a scope error, couple of syntax errors. So the errors.

Comment: This solution will match partial test codes. For example, given the codes provided in the question, entering 'T' into the input field would return true for `lines.indexOf($("#test-code").val()) !== -1`.

Comment: I added a check for string length. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @goldenparrot actually, I didn't see that you were still splitting `lines` into an array. The length check isn't needed if you're doing this. my mistake.

Comment: Thanks for replying but same issue it always only show the error message. here is my test site url where you can see it in action. [link](http://store.cotintheweb.com/testing-code.html)

Comment: It's working for CLUB1234. Something must've been wrong with the file encoding i guess. Use a csv instead for text file, and split using ',' instead of '\n' in code

Comment: Brilliant it works one more little thing, anyway to hide the path of the file so when viewed thru page source they can't see the path. Thanks

Comment: You have to do a server side check for that not, like using php. Javascript won't do!

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid an array loop altogether by creating a regular expression that ensures the test code is found between word boundaries:

```
var codeRegEx = new RegExp('\\b'+$('#test-code').val()+'\\b');
if(codeRegEx.test(lines)) {
   // the testcode is found on a single line, avoiding partial matches
}
```

Here's a demo:

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vnjkp/)